# How to make multiple eta reductions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a task to get a column from a `[[a]]` matrix.

A simple solution would be

```
colFields :: Int -> [[a]] -> [a]
colFields n c = map (!! n) c
```

and when reduced by one level of abstraction it would be

```
colFields n = map (!! n)
```

I sense that I could get rid of `n` easily, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
colFields = map . flip (!!)
```

However, this is not very clear to read, I'd leave the `n` parameter in there.  With the `n` as an explicit parameter, I understand immediately what the function does.  Without it, I have to think for a minute in order to understand the definition, even for a simple case like this.

I obtained this answer very simply by using the [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool, although there are methods for deriving this by hand.

Comment: I agree it's not super clear and the pointful version is preferable. I figured it out manually; here's my train of thought: "I wish I had `pointfree` installed. `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`. If I get that `Int` to be the first parameter I can compose it with `(.)`. That's what `flip` is for. Let's ask `ghci`: `:t flip (!!)`; `:t map . flip (!!)`. That looks good. Oh darn, @bheklilr beat me to it."

Comment: @ChristianConkle To be fair I just copy/pasted the code into my already open GHCi with `:pf` set up to call the `pointfree` tool.  Once I saw the suggested reduction I thought "Oh yeah, you'd have to use `flip` on `(!!)` to get the `n` to be consumed first, then pass that result to `map` using `(.)`.  I _understand_ the pointfree version, but it wasn't without a small amount of effort.  The pointful version is immediately clear to me (maybe I write too much Haskell...)

Comment: A bit of nerding here... `flip (!!) :: Int -> [a] -> a` a more natural function from a partial application standpoint than `(!!)`, where the argument order is for notation purposes. Perhaps I would call it `index`. And in that case `map . index` is nice.  But I agree `map . flip (!!)` is a bit convoluted to read as-is.