# Discard variables through use of dot and dollar

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner and I want to know why we can discard certain variables when using certain operators, for example:

```
     last xs = head (reverse xs)
     last'   = head . reverse
```

Another example:

```
     example p xs = length (filter p xs)
     example' p = length . filter p
```

Why can't we toss the p in this function?

Comment: The `.` operator is called "composition". The `$` is called "application". Juxtaposition, e.g. `f x`, is also application. If you search for the operator names, you should find good explanations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make multiple eta reductions in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538438/how-to-make-multiple-eta-reductions-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [point-free notation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree). For your example, it is:

```
example' = (length .) . filter
```

though it is harder to comprehend, in my opinion.

There is a convenient tool to generate point-free version: [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/)

Answer (score 6):

You don't “discard” the variables there, you merely *don't mention* them. The process is called [eta-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion): thanks to referential transparency, when you define

```
g x = f x
```

you might just as well simply write `g = f`. This also works when `f` is not already a named function, like

```
last' xs = (head . reverse) xs
 ⇒ last' =  head . reverse
```

But this requires that the variable actually turns up only as the final argument to a self-contained function, e.g. one that is already named or enclosed in parens. For instance, with your original `last` this is not possible because the `xs` occurs *in* the parenthesis `(reverse xs)`, hence you first need to transform `head (reverse xs) ≡ (head . reverse) xs` before you can η-reduce it. Likewise,

```
length . filter p ≡ length . (filter p)
```

so you can't just reduce the `p` because it's inside a parenthesis. You can however, as bereal suggests, consider the precomposition `(length .)` as a seperate function that's applied to the rest of the expression:

```
length . filter p
  ≡ (length .) (filter p)
  ≡ ((length .) . filter) p
example' = (length .) . filter
```

But I agree that this makes the code rather harder to read, hence I'd normally leave `example'` as it is.

Comment: For the first paragraph, I don't see how referential transparency is relevant (in this specific case).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: https://tio.run/##Zc5dC8IgFAbge3/FwQh0tNbqUvon3Qz1qFAuzMEg9ttNW6OvKz@e874cWRspU1o5L8@D0kBvUbl@aykhzkfAHSvHyOEedByCh7Hai2m29t8O2Z7IKuSFORxziZg/zW8A2ciXxKVzHlg2AjA32HeDAGga0LGrg1aD1AqwDxfoEQzJ81hmWlGu15AzyKhhbUmu3cnTDZQXFx9sv9gu/NorLzyl9AA

Comment: Or if you prefer Python https://tio.run/##XctBCsMgFITh/TvFkBLQQiE2u0Jv0o2pPg00GsSCPb2J0C7S5fwfs36yj2GslQfc8dLLZDTKDeV8JVZ/aSTiPfFA5A7EokjyjYATbNaXZM37aQ04pgWR4b5XRbSmOWTROaHkXvr5ETr0aFP@zB@tTVnrBg